# wrap template component with his name

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have components and I would like every component template wrapped inside a div with his name.

```
Vue.component('search', {
        template: '<div>component template</div>'
```

html result

```
<div class="component-search">
      <div>component template</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi. I haven't comprehensive solution, but I think Vue Render Functions may help. Or look closer to your Vue Loader API. There are many cool features provided.

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine why you would want to be do that but anyhow you could do the following

```
Vue.component('search', {
    name: 'search',

    template: `<div :class="wrapperClass">
        <div>component template</div>
    </div>`,

    computed: {
        componentName() {
            return this.$options.name
        },

        wrapperClass() {
            return `component-${this.componentName}`
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: The reason : test selenium. I want a way to select the component and sub value. The quickest way a thought was to have a sort of extension of vue (maybe native) where the template render is done, its also wrap into a div with a class named with componentName. I want to not do it manually.

Comment: @forX So did what I suggest help in any way.

Comment: I never create a vue extension. The information of options.name is interesting, but I will not do that on every component.